# Convert Json to image PNG in html

Tags: json, ruby, base64, png

I have a big json like this:

```
{"mime_type":"image/png", "data":"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...JSON GOES ON..."}
```

and in HTML i have a IMAGE with comes from the JSON above, but the IMG is already converted to another format.

```
<img class="materialboxed" data-caption='Criar um usuario valido na plataforma' width="250" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABZAAAAJ7CAYAAAB9DbSSAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c
6QAAIABJREFUeJzs3XtUVXXex/H3UUS8djASMEnBS2JeQNECK5XSScAaISv1sZ6i1NL0KbWZ1BJLbSqtyUtpRU016lSjVio1mmhZ4KSBt4TygoXJwVAQQY6A7uePA8jlnAMoqNnntZZrwf5d9u/3Oxtbff3y3SbDMAxERERERERERERE5IqSm5t7wXM0qIN1iIiIiIiIiIiIiMgVSAFkEREREREREREREbFLAWQRERERERER...IMG GOES ON.... /img>
```

I would like to know how this conversion process takes place and if there is any library in ruby that does this.

Comment: A JSON image does not make sense. Here, you have a JSON which contains PNG data. I don't know in what format though. In your HTML, you have the image with PNG data too, but in base64. I think what you might need actually is how to decode base64. Please be clearer and mention why you want to convert that image

Comment: The data string in the JSON is also base64 encoded. When you base64 decode the data string `aVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQUF...` you get `iVBORw0KGgoAAA...`.  which is the base64 encoded binary image data.  So actually the JSON contains the double encoded image data.

Comment: ok thanks a lot your comments give me a light!!